# changed field in filebeat but not working in logstash

Tags: nginx, logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat

I changed the source from access to admin and restarted the filebeat service, when I use grok to filter only the admin source, it is empty, but if using grok to filter only the access, it working. It should be source admin not access, if there any other configuration part I missed? I checked the kibana, the log have field.source = admin

```
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /etc/nginx/log/admin.log

  fields:
    source: admin
```

```
if "admin" in [source]{

mutate{
remove_field => ["event.original"]

}


 grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:remote_ip} - %{DATA:user_name} \[%{HTTPDATE:time}\] \"%{WORD:method}%{DATA:url} HTTP/%{NUMBER:http_version}\" %{NUMBER:response_code} %{NUMBER:body_sent:bytes} \"%{DATA:referrer}\" \"%{DATA:agent}\" \"%{NUMBER:request_time}\"  \"%{DATA:http_x_forwarded_for}\" %{IPORHOST:http_host} " }
        remove_field => "message"
        remove_field => "event.original"
    }
}
```

[kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpV5a.png)

I would like to filter only the fields source = admin to match the message and separate the content

Comment: logstash can distinguish between an object called event which contains a field called original ("[event][original]"), and a field name that has a period embedded ("[event.original]"). This is not the same notation used by kibana and elasticsearch.

Comment: @Badger Thank you for the information, for the if statement part, I wondering do you have any idea?